# SMTP RCPT TO Testing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, email, smtp

I am developing an email validation tool for a client.  One feature they are requesting is to confirm that an mailbox exist on the mail server for the email address being tested.  I've implemented the SMTP protocol using a TCP client in C#, however when I try to issue the MAIL FROM command I get an error message saying that I'm not authenticated; this has occurred while attempting to validate email address on GMail.

I know this should be possible as the client provided a link to a service which does something similar (https://www.upwork.com/leaving?ref=https://verifalia.com/validate-email).  Using that site, if I enter my valid GMail addresses, it returns the proper information (that one is valid and that another is over quota).  If I then change one letter of the address it properly reports that the mailbox does not exist.  I am trying to implement the same features, but based on the error message I am getting it seems almost like I would need to have an account on Google.

However, this does not make sense to me.  How does any other SMTP server connect to GMail (or for that matter, any other SMTP server) to deliver mail?  Every server can't have an account on every other server.  I am just trying to get the SMTP protocol to work up to the DATA element (as I don't want to send an actual email).

Any information or help would be greatly appreciated.  I have included my current code below.  Please note that this code is not currently optimized and I plan on improving it once the protocol is working.  In addition, the MAIL FROM address I have been using isn't actually test@example (I have tried using a GMail, AIM, and other addresses but all have resulted in the same error).

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {
            host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            var port = 465;
            client.Connect(host, port);
            // as gmail requires ssl we should use sslstream
            // if your smtp server doesn't support ssl you can
            // work directly with the underlying stream
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            using (var sslstream = new SslStream(stream))
            {
                sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(sslstream))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sslstream))
                {
                    string read = "";
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        read = reader.ReadLine();
                    }

                    if (!read.StartsWith("220"))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine("EHLO " + host);
                    writer.Flush();

                    do
                    {
                        read = reader.ReadLine();
                    } while (read.StartsWith("250-"));


                    if (read.StartsWith("220") || read.StartsWith("250"))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("mail from:<test@example.com>\r\n");
                        writer.Flush();
                        read = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (read.StartsWith("530"))
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                read = reader.ReadLine();
                            } while (read.StartsWith("530-"));
                        }
                        if (read.StartsWith("250"))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("rcpt to:<" + _emailAddress + ">");
                            writer.Flush();
                            read = reader.ReadLine();
                            if (read.StartsWith("250"))
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("quit");
                                writer.Flush();
                                read = reader.ReadLine();
                                if (read.StartsWith("221"))
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("quit");
                                writer.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("quit");
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("quit");
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                    // gmail responds with: 220 mx.google.com esmtp
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the receiving servers for gmail.com, for me the response is

```
host -t mx gmail.com
gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

As for what smtp.gmail.com is

```
host smtp.gmail.com
smtp.gmail.com is an alias for gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 108.177.127.109
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 108.177.127.108
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4013:c00::6d
```

As you can see these aren't the same thing. If you want to send mail to gmail.com addresses you'll need to use the servers defined in the MX records. And as you can see from the names, there's "gmail-smtp-in" in the names which shows they're for incoming email. The server you're using is for sending email through Google servers.

So change the server to one actually receiving mail for the domain in question and try again.